# The if statement wont read vairables

Tags: javascript, if-statement, timeout

I cant get my if statements to run it will only run the count down portion but the specifics like when it gets to 5 and 0 it just wont run those extra if statements.

```js
function Countdown()
{
    var currTime = 10;

    var i = 10;

    while (i>=0) {

        if (currTime == 5)
        {
            setTimeout(function () {

                document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Warning Less than ½ way to launch, time left = " + currTime;
    
                currTime = currTime - 1;
    
            }, 1000 * i);
    
            i -= 1;
        }
        if (currTime == 0)
        {
            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "Blast OFF"; 
        }
        else
        {
        setTimeout(function () {

            document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = "the time left is " + currTime;

            currTime = currTime - 1;

        }, 1000 * i);

        i -= 1; /* same as i = i-1 */
        }
    };

 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually your while loop execute the currTime 11 times here. The main issue is here you are using interval of 1 sec or 1 sec+ etc, but your loop runs very fast in ms of 100 or 500 which excecute currTime very fast. That's the issue here. I hope you got the issue.

Comment: if I change my interval would that fix my if statement